# How to remove child nodes in firebase android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a number of child nodes in my firebase db and I want to delete only one child node.

```
Firebase firebase=new Firebase("..address..");

firebase.push().setValue(classObj);
```

//here classObj is a class object which has a getter and setter for an integer id

Now that I have pushed multiple objects I want to delete only one based on the id in the classObj

Answer (score 81, accepted):

To remove data:

```
firebase.child(id).removeValue();
```

You might do well to have a look at the Firebase documentation for Android btw, which covers this and many more topics.

Comment: By using push, a random id is generated. So how did you get the id in firebase.child(id).removeValue()?

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to first remove .push() from the DatabaseReference.

Comment: Push returns a databasereference and you can getkey from it to know the id

Comment: you can get the push key's value following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38232280/5572246. And then after that its simply: firebase.child(pushKeyValue).removeValue()

Comment: @Akhil How does removeValue  remove the key as well?

Comment: Firebase only stores a path when there is a value at that path. So removing a value, will remove the key for that value too. In fact, if removing a value makes en entire branch of your JSON empty, it will remove that entire branch.

Answer (score 15):

### If you are using DatabaseReference for firebase

```
DatabaseReference dbNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot().child("Node");
```

*Here Node represents the child which you wish to delete*

```
dbNode.setValue(null);
```

---

### If you are using a dataSnapshot

i.e., while you are working on some data change events

```
dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove a Node or child node

```
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

database.getReference("root_node_name")
   .child("child_node_name")
   .removeValue();
```

To remove Sub-child node

```
database.getReference("root_node_name")
   .child("child_node_name")
   .child("sub_child_node_name")
   .removeValue();
```

Comment: how to remove the "sub_child_node_name" if "child_node_name" is not known

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this code:

```
 Firebase firebase=new Firebase(URL);
    firebase.child(id).removeValue();
```