# How to remove specific value from Firebase database? I want to remove table13 from "Occupied" and transfer it to "Available"

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-studio-3.0

I want to Delete Specific value from Firebase Database following is Database which i have stored

[image: My problem is all value from occupied is transfered to occupied [2]

Comment: which value do you want to remove?

Comment: table13 and transfer it to available @akhilesh0707

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove child nodes in firebase android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185620/how-to-remove-child-nodes-in-firebase-android)

Comment: Why are you using two separate nodes for the tables, available and occupied?

Answer (score 1):

To remove specific child nodes in `Firebase` you need to call set value `null` on that particular node Or you can call `databaseReference.removeValue();`

Try below code it will solve your problem

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("table").child("occupied");
databaseReference.setValue(null);
```

**Update:**
You are using a `dataSnapshot` try this

```
dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
```

Comment: then how to transfer it to available ?

Comment: get values in local variable and update value to `available` node and then remove

Comment: dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null); remove all values from "occupied" i only need to remove specific data

Comment: @Saw then call `dataSnapshot.getRef().child("Table13").setValue(null)`

Comment: Sorry mate newbie here.. the 
 dataSnapshot.getRef().child("Table13").setValue(null) only transfer the data but it doesn't remove in occupied

Comment: so you want to remove `occupied` node then call `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("table").child("occupied");` it will removed occupied node as well as all child node

Comment: i only need to delete specific in occupied .. can you give me  code structure for it ?

Comment: try this `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("table").child("occupied").child("table13").removeValue();`

Answer (score 1):

You have to do that in a few steps:

1. Load in device memory data which you want to remove.
2. Remove from firebase data which you already loaded.
3. Write data from memory to new firebase database node.

But is not a best solution... here you must handle a few marginal cases like application interruption on step 2. Of course you can handle that but here is a lot of code which must be written and maintained. I suggest you to use [firebase cloud funtions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). To put that 3 steps to cloud functions and just to handle results in firebase realtime database listeners, just 1 call to cloud functions to obtain amazing results :)

Also in firebase cloud functions you can put a listener to your "available" node which will be triggered when some node data will be removed. In that listener you can get that data which must be removed and move it to "occupied" node. From my point of view that solution is a little bit simpler.